# How to add an existing feature class to a new feature dataset

Tags: arcobjects, c#, feature-class, feature-dataset

I have a feature class.

```
IFeatureClass AOIfc = AOIfws.OpenFeatureClass("BrigadeAOI");
```

I need to be able to put this feature class into a feature dataset that is newly created.  The following line of code doesn't work for me.

```
IFeatureDataset AOIfd = AOIfc.FeatureDataset;
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please tag this post with the appropriate software/languages?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this using [IDatasetContainer.AddDataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddDataset_Method/002500000159000000/).

From the [IDatasetContainer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IDatasetContainer_Interface/00250000014t000000/) documentation:

> The IDatasetContainer interface lets you move datasets between feature
>   datasets and workspaces. Both objects implement the interface. It
>   should only be used to move datasets between feature datasets and the
>   workspace level within a single workspace, however; it cannot be used
>   to transfer datasets from one workspace to another.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ended up just doing this using ArcCatalog.  I won't try to create this in the code.